How Can I show just values of the dicitionary on HTML?
I have created a function to get some date from database, make some calculations and show it in HTML files. However I could not to get just values from views.
def list_pay(request):
    item = Pay.objects.all()

    # Quantidades
    q_total = Pay.objects.all().count
    q_open = Pay.objects.filter(status=0).count
    q_paied = Pay.objects.filter(status=1).count

    # Soma dos valores
    v_total = Pay.objects.aggregate(Sum('value'))
    v_open = Pay.objects.filter(status=0).aggregate(Sum('value'))
    v_paied = Pay.objects.filter(status=1).aggregate(Sum('value'))


    data = {
        'item':item,
        'v_total':v_total,
        'v_open':v_open,
        'v_paied':v_paied,
        'q_total':q_total,
        'q_open':q_open,
        'q_paied':q_paied
        }
        
    return render(request, 'pay/list_pay.html', data)

<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <h3 class="mb-3 mt-3">Lista <span class="text-success">de pagamentos</span></h3>

    <div class="col m-3 p-3">
        <label>Total de boletos</label>
        <h1 class="text-primary"> {{ q_total }}</h1>
        <h1 class="text-primary"> {{ v_total }}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col m-3 p-3">
        <span>Quantidade de boletos</span>
        <h1 class="text-success">{{ q_paied }}</h1>
        <h1 class="text-success">{{ v_paied }}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col m-3 p-3">
        <span>Quantidade de boletos</span>
        <h1 class="text-danger">{{ q_open }}</h1>
        <h1 class="text-danger">{{ v_open }}</h1>
    </div>
</div>

The current value loaded = {'value__sum': 1831}. The expected output = 1831
I alredy try .values() and transform the dict in a list and other format.

"I alredy try .values() and transform the dict in a list and other format." - and what happened? How it did not work?

Shouldn't that be q_total = Pay.objects.all().count() ? With ()

Perform a lookup, so:
<h1 class="text-success">{{ v_paied.value__sum }}</h1>
or, you can perform the lookup in the view:
v_paied = Pay.objects.filter(status=1).aggregate(Sum('value'))['value__sum']
That being said, you are currently performing multiple queries that can be combined in one SQL query.
Indeed, we can use:
from django.db.models import Count, Q, Sum

def list_pay(request):
    data = Pay.objects.aggregate(
        q_total=Count('pk'),
        q_open=Count('pk', filter=Q(status=0)),
        q_paied=Count('pk', filter=Q(status=1)),
        v_total=Sum('value'),
        v_open=Sum('value', filter=Q(status=0)),
        v_paied=Sum('value', filter=Q(status=1)),
    )
    data['item'] = Pay.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'pay/list_pay.html', data)
So here we make at most two database queries.

You should be able to get all of this in a single aggregate query with something like
def list_pay(request):
    pay_items = Pay.objects.all()
    aggregate_data = pay_items.aggregate(
        q_open=Count("id", filter=Q(status=0)),
        q_paied=Count("id", filter=Q(status=1)),
        q_total=Count("id"),
        v_open=Sum("value", filter=Q(status=0)),
        v_paied=Sum("value", filter=Q(status=1)),
        v_total=Sum("value"),
    )

    data = {
        "item": pay_items,
        **aggregate_data,
    }

    return render(request, "pay/list_pay.html", data)


We had the same idea :).
